# Cambiar cantidad de filas y columnas en vista CakePhp

Tags: ajax, mvc, cakephp

en mi empresa me pasaron el requerimiento de disminuir la cantidad de columnas a 3 y que no se muestren 5 filas sino 16, la cosa es que no entiendo como le están diciendo al código que solo muestre esa cantidad de filas y columnas, aquí les paso como se ve ahora :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código es el siguiente:

```
<div id="used_list"><!-- the total columns U most SUM 12 -->


    <?php
        foreach ($UseCar as $car) {
            echo "<section>";
            echo "<h3>".substr($car['UseCar']['title'], 0, 23)."</h3>";
            if(!empty($car['UseImage'])){
                echo $this->Html->image('uploads/'.$car['UseImage'][0]['id'].'/'.$car['UseImage'][0]['image'], array('alt' => $car['UseCar']['title'], 'title' => $car['UseImage'][0]['title']));
            }else{
                $noImage = 'no_pic_available.jpg';
                if ($car['UseCar']['state'] == 'Por entrar') {
                    $noImage = 'no_pic_available_next.jpg';
                }
                echo $this->Html->image($noImage, array('alt' => 'Sin Imágen', 'title' => 'Imágen no disponible'));
            }
            if($car['UseCar']['promo_week']){
                echo $this->Html->image('promo_week.png', 
                    array('alt' => 'Oferta de la semana', 'class' => 'used_promo_banner'));
            }else if($car['UseCar']['promo_day']){
                echo $this->Html->image('promo_today.
                    png', array('alt' => 'Solo por Hoy', 'class' => 'used_promo_banner'));
            }
            echo "<p class='price'>".$this->Number->currency($car['UseCar']['price'], '$ ', 
                    array('thousands' => '.', 'places' => '0'))."</p>";
            echo "<p>".$car['UseCar']['year']."<span> | </span>".$car['UseCar']['kilometre']."Km</p>";


            $onclick = $this->Js->request(
                  array('controller' => 'used', 'action' => 'infoAjax', 
                     $car['UseCar']['id']), 
                  array('async' => true, 'update' => '#blackbox_content'));

            echo $this->Html->link('', array('action' => 'index', 'id' => $car['UseCar']['id']), 
              array('onclick' => 'display_blackbox(); '.$onclick, 'class' => 'use_link', 'title' => $car['UseCar']['title']));

            echo "</section>";
        }               
    ?>
</div>
```

Ese es el código que recorre toda la BD, pero como mencione anteriormente no se donde le dicen que solo ponga 5 filas y 4 columnas.
El jefe menciono que eso estaba hecho por ajax por el anterior desarrollador pero no veo donde llaman a un ajax en ese código.

Comment: inspecciona la página con el devtools  y busca algún patrón, con ese códgo que has puesto no soy capaz de ver nada, podrías decir la página que es y se le puede echar un ojo.
Opino que el anterior desarrollador no hizo un buen trabajo...

Comment: Así a simple vista podría ser que el tag `section` tenga estilos asignados para ocupar un 25%...

Comment: Listo, gracias, ya encontré la solución, esta en el controlador y los estilo.

Comment: El estilo tenia esto así:
`#usados #used_list section {
                ...
  width: 24%;
  ...
 }`
Y lo cambie por esto:
`#usados #used_list section {
  ...
  width: 30%;
  ...
 }`

Comment: El controlador tenia esto: 
`public function indexAjax($id = null){
                      ...
                      $this->Paginator->settings = array( 'conditions' => array('enable' => '1', 'state NOT' => array('Vendido')), 'order' => array('UseCar.promo_week' => 'DESC', 'UseCar.promo_day' => 'DESC', 
            'UseCar.id' => 'ASC'),'limit' => 20
    );
                       ...
}`
Y lo cambie por esto:
`public function indexAjax($id = null){
                      ...
                     $this->... 
          'limit' => 48
    );
                       ...
}`